# CMake for UHD Library can't find Boost

Tags: compiling, c++, cmake, boost

I'm trying to build the UHD library (https://github.com/EttusResearch/uhd.git) on Ubuntu 20.04 and when I run `cmake ..` from `host/build`, I get this message:

```
-- Checking for Boost version 1.58 or greater
--   Looking for required Boost components...
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: chrono date_time filesystem program_options
  serialization thread unit_test_framework system) (found suitable version
  "1.71.0", minimum required is "1.58")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2179 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  cmake/Modules/UHDBoost.cmake:176 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:296 (include)
```

This is really confusing to me for two reasons:

- It says it found a suitable version (1.71.0 with 1.58 being the minimum), but it still somehow failed.
- I've got another machine running Ubuntu 20.04 where this works and I can't find any differences in the environment.  It's the exact same version of CMake (3.16.3), exact same version of Boost (1.71.0), etc.  I get the same Boost libraries in the same paths when I run `ldconfig -p` and my LIBRARY_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variables are the same.

Having it work on another machine with a (seemingly) identical environment makes me optimistic that this should be solvable.  Does anyone have an idea of what next steps I could take in troubleshooting?  Thanks!

Comment: Have you [tried this possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54757097/cmake-cannot-find-boost-libraries-filestem-thread-date-time-iostreams-system)?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that one and it didn't work.  I think it's got to be a problem with the environment, not CMake because the exact same repo (exact same CMake files) work on a different machine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow [official compilation guide](https://files.ettus.com/manual/page_build_guide.html) and install many development packages by

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev doxygen python3-docutils python3-mako python3-numpy python3-requests python3-ruamel.yaml python3-setuptools cmake build-essential
```

and then retry.

Or simpler - install binary UHD [packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&searchon=all&keywords=ettus) by

```
sudo apt-get install libuhd-dev uhd-host gnuradio
```

Comment: APT says it's already installed: `libboost-all-dev is already the newest version (1.71.0.0ubuntu2)`

Comment: I do not know why exactly you are trying to compile UHD, but please note that it is packaged in Ubuntu - see [search results](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&searchon=all&keywords=ettus).

Comment: Yeah, I installed all those packages and I'm still getting the same result.  I also know about the pre-compiled binaries and I've used them a bunch, but I want to build from source so I can experiment with some modifications to the UHD library,